# How to add column data to the first row only in pandas OR provide default data for new column entries?

Tags: python, pandas

not the exact code, but simplified:

```
df['running_total'] = df.running_total.shift() + df['total']
```

obviously, in the first instance `df.running_total.shift()` the entry doesn't exist so it errors out.

There is a special calculation for the first entry so I'd like to set it explicitly. Or use that calculation as the default value whenever the prev row entry can't be found or DNE.

Either solution would work, prefer the faster solution (small data set, called infrequently).

Comment: You could do `df['running_total'] = df['running_total'].fillna(some_val)` where `some_val` is the value you want to fill all NaNs with.

Comment: @coldspeed So that would fill all rows with the first row data and then I'd write over it, yes?

Comment: Correct. Is that what you want?

Comment: @coldspeed I'd rather run through the rows only once, filling where no data is available -but this is better than my non-solution! thanks :D

Comment: You can't do that without a loop, and I wouldn't recommend doing that because `fillna` is much faster than a python loop.

Comment: Is there any chance that you would put some small snippet of data in your question, Incase you are looking for better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'running_total':[4,5,np.nan, np.nan]})
print (df)
   running_total
0            4.0
1            5.0
2            NaN
3            NaN

print (df.running_total.shift())
0    NaN
1    4.0
2    5.0
3    NaN
Name: running_total, dtype: float64
```

One possible solution is [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) - but it replace all `NaN`s

```
print (df.running_total.shift().fillna(0))
0    0.0
1    4.0
2    5.0
3    0.0
Name: running_total, dtype: float64
```

If want replace only first value, set it by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) (`iloc`, `loc`):

```
shifted = df.running_total.shift()
shifted.iat[0] = 0
print (shifted)
0    0.0
1    4.0
2    5.0
3    NaN
Name: running_total, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I liked `iat[0]` nice one sir.

Comment: oh neat! i didn't know you could change the value of shifted like that.

Comment: I see my solution is unaccepted. Thete is some problem? Can tou explain?